# Animating the border color of an <input>: border turns black first

Tags: google-chrome, css, animation

When I try to animate the border-color of an  the border first turns black, then turns blue (blue is the color I want it to be). The black intermezzo looks really ugly, so I came here to ask if it is a known issue and if there is a workaround.

A JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZBWQx/

The CSS involved:

```
input:not([type="submit"]) {
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 3px;
}
input:not([type="submit"]):focus {
    border-color: #6d9eeb;
    transition-property: border-color;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition-property: border-color;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -o-transition-property: border-color;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.5s;
    -moz-transition-property: border-color;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.5s;
}
input {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Although I did use the other vendor prefixes above, portability is not important. It only needs to work in Chrome. (But it might be convenient for future readers to find a solution working in Firefox too here.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me, if you have't set the initial border-color, it defaults to black.

Adding `border-color: #eeeeee;` to the input selector seems to solve the problem, at least for me on OSX Safari.